# Configure Maven to use javac -O

Tags: java, maven, optimization, maven-3, javac

There is a option javac -O to compile the optimized java code according to the Javac manual. Can I use maven to use this flag?

Answer (score 5):

Hi you need to configure the [maven-compiler-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/usage.html) like this:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <optimize>true</optimize>
            ...
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: This is likely the better solution as it is clear what you are doing due to the xml element being named `<optimize>`.  The more specific documentation link for the comile mojo can be found [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html).

Answer (score -2):

From [the documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/pass-compiler-arguments.html), you could do something like this:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <compilerArgument>-O</compilerArgument>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    [...]
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```